# TableView - Move up and Move down functionality of a cell

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I have a situation where I have a `TableView`. I'm trying to implement a feature that allows a cell to be moved up or down. After moving the cell up or down (with the cell content), I want to change focus to the new location of the cell.

The problem is that it doesn't change to the new location. It for some reason stays in the original selected cell location.

This is the code used to move up, move down and change focus:

I am attempting to move a single selected cell.

```
public class TableController
{
    private ObservableList<SimpleStringProperty> observablePrnPropertyData;

    @FXML
    private TableView<SimpleStringProperty> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<SimpleStringProperty, String> data;        

    @FXML
    private void initialize()
    {
        this.data.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue());
        this.data.setCellFactory(event -> new EditCell(this.observablePrnPropertyData, this.table));
    }

    public void display(final PrnProperty prnProperty)
    {
        this.observablePrnPropertyData = PrnPropertyUtil.getObservableDataFromPrnProperty(prnProperty);
        this.table.setItems(this.observablePrnPropertyData);
    }


    private final class EditCell extends TableCell<SimpleStringProperty, String>
    {
        @Override
        public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
        {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (empty)
            {
                this.setText(null);
                this.setGraphic(null);
            }
            else
            {
                this.setUpContextMenu();

                this.setText(this.getString());
                this.setGraphic(null);
            }
        }

        private void setUpContextMenu()
        {
            // Context menu
            ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

            // context menu Move up
            this.moveUp = new MenuItem("Move up");
            this.moveUp.setOnAction(event -> this.moveUp(this.table, this.observablePrnPropertyData));
            contextMenu.getItems().add(this.moveUp);

            // Context menu for move down
            this.moveDown = new MenuItem("Move down");
            this.moveDown.setOnAction(event -> this.moveDown(this.table, this.observablePrnPropertyData));
            contextMenu.getItems().add(this.moveDown);

            // Add context menu
            this.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        }

        public void moveUp(final TableView<?> table, ObservableList listToManipulate)
        {
            final int selectedIndex = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

            final Object removeItem = listToManipulate.remove(selectedIndex);

            final int newIndex = selectedIndex - 1;
            listToManipulate.add(newIndex, removeItem);
            this.changeTableCellFocus(table, newIndex);
        }

        public void moveDown(final TableView<?> table, ObservableList listToManipulate)
        {
            final int selectedIndex = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();

            final Object remove = listToManipulate.remove(selectedIndex);

            final int newIndex = selectedIndex + 1;
            listToManipulate.add(newIndex, remove);
            this.changeTableCellFocus(table, newIndex);
        }

        public void changeTableCellFocus(final TableView<?> table, final int focusIndex)
        {
            table.requestFocus();
            table.getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(focusIndex);
            table.getFocusModel().focus(focusIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

It would be great if someone can give a working example. I really want to know what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: Can you give some more code on how you create the table. This is important because at the moment I can't tell from your code whether you are trying to move a single cell or a complete row. Moreover the databinding is important, so if you have that in another location, add that code too.

Comment: I have made some changes to the code to include more information.

Comment: Your code will move the whole row, not just a single cell (though it looks like right now you only have one column). This is a complete hack, but try wrapping the calls to `changeTableCellFocus(...)` in a `Platform.runLater(...)`.

Comment: I've tried `Platform.runLater(...)` and I'm still having the same problem. The whole row moved up but, the focus doesn't change to the new row location.

Comment: javafx-1 "= javafx script is irrelevant" here and in all of your other javafx questions!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use arrow buttons to traverse cells in edit mode in TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330430/how-to-use-arrow-buttons-to-traverse-cells-in-edit-mode-in-tableview)

Answer (score 0):

If you just have to focus next and previous line, you can try: table.getFocusModel().focusNext() and .focusPrevious(), like described here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/FocusModel.html

Comment: I've tried that and I'm still having the same problem. I must be doing something wrong but not exactly sure what it is. It would be great if someone can give a working example.

Answer (score 0):

For your case use this code will work fine, it is simple you must first get the selected index, move the item to the next (or previous) row, then select this new row.

```
void upClicked(){
    if(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null) // check if the user really selected a row in the table
    {
        if(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != 0) // if the row first one so do nothing
        {
            int index = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex(); // get the selected row index
            SimpleStringProperty x = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem(); // get the selected item
            table.getItems().set(index, table.getItems().get(index-1)); // move the selected item up
            table.getItems().set(index-1, x); // change the row with the item in above
            table.getSelectionModel().select(index-1); // select the new row position
        }
    }
}

void downClicked(){
    if(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() != null)
    {
        if(table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() != table.getItems().size()-1) // if the row is in last so dont do nothing
        {
            int index = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            SimpleStringProperty x = table.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            table.getItems().set(index, table.getItems().get(index+1));
            table.getItems().set(index+1, x);
            table.getSelectionModel().select(index+1);
        }
    }
}
```