# How to use arrow buttons to traverse cells in edit mode in TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I'd like to use the arrow/enter keys to traverse the cells in `TableView`, however, if I try to implement it in my custom EditCell class, it doesn't seem to work.  Is there a way to make this happen? I've tried a listener on the `TextField` but it doesn't actually start the focus in the actual cell.

Here is my code:

**Tester.java**

```
package tester;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableRow;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class Tester extends Application
{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {

        TableView<LineItem> table = new TableView<>();

        Callback<TableColumn<LineItem, String>, TableCell<LineItem, String>> textFactoryEditable = (TableColumn<LineItem, String> p) -> new EditableTextCell();

        TableColumn<LineItem, String> column1 = new TableColumn<>("Test1");
        column1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getString1Property());
        column1.setEditable(true);
        column1.setCellFactory(textFactoryEditable);

        table.getColumns().add(column1);

        TableColumn<LineItem, String> column2 = new TableColumn<>("Test2");
        column2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getString2Property());
        column2.setEditable(true);
        column2.setCellFactory(textFactoryEditable);

        table.getColumns().add(column2);

        table.getItems().add(new LineItem());
        table.getItems().add(new LineItem());
        table.getItems().add(new LineItem());

        table.setPrefWidth(500);

        HBox root = new HBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(table);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**LineItem.java**

```
package tester;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;

public class LineItem
{

    private final StringProperty string1;
    private final StringProperty string2;

    public LineItem()
    {
        this.string1 = new SimpleStringProperty();
        this.string2 = new SimpleStringProperty();
    }

    public final StringProperty getString1Property()
    {
        return this.string1;
    }

    public final StringProperty getString2Property()
    {
        return this.string2;
    }
}
```

**EditableTextCell.java**

```
package tester;

import java.util.Objects;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.beans.value.WritableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;

public class EditableTextCell<E> extends TableCell<E, String>
{

    private final TextField textField;
    private boolean updating = false;

    public EditableTextCell()
    {
        textField = new TextField();
        textField.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);


        textField.textProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends String> o, String oldValue, String newValue) ->
        {

            if (!updating)
            {
                ((WritableValue<String>) getTableColumn().getCellObservableValue((E) getTableRow().getItem())).setValue(newValue);
                getTableView().scrollTo(getTableRow().getIndex());
                getTableView().scrollToColumn(getTableColumn());
            }

        });

        textField.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke) ->
        {
            switch (ke.getCode())
            {
                case DOWN:
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focusBelowCell();
                    break;
                case UP:
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focusAboveCell();
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focusRightCell();
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focusLeftCell();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty)
        {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else
        {
            setGraphic(textField);
            if (!Objects.equals(textField.getText(), item))
            {
                // prevent own updates from moving the cursor
                updating = true;
                textField.setText(item);
                updating = false;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Haven't analyzed your code in depth, but I noticed you don't appear to [enable cell selection](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableSelectionModel.html#cellSelectionEnabledProperty). By default a `TableView` is in "row selection" mode.

Comment: Thanks, that did it. Now I was able to add a listener on the FocusProperty, can you tell me if this is the best way? It seems to be working ...

Comment: So there is no way to do this without enabling that setting?

Comment: Are your cells supposed to be in "permanent editing" mode?

Comment: beware: your cell implementation is by-passing the edit mechanism, that's an absolute no-no-never! You _must not_ change the backing data on the fly. Bug hacking in a tightly controlled context might be an exception to the rule *mumbling .. but generally, don't don't don't

Comment: @Slaw yes, always in edit mode.

Comment: @kleopatra it was set an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50408920/9278333 so I thought it was fine.

Comment: This was an absolute requirement, to have data dynamically update while the user typed, and not have to double click into a field.

Comment: thanks for the link :) commented the answer as well .. and will mark the change-on-typing as a possibly - have to think it through, though - valid exception of the rule :)

Comment: re-reading your requirement: is it really on-typing? (are there any direct (per-character) actions that are triggered from the model? you are aware that this can work only for String typed values?) or is it the missing commit-on-focusLost support in core fx?

Comment: This is the issue with table view that it doesn’t work that great as an edit table. Users can’t add/edit data efficiently on the “edit, then commit model”.  If I can’t use this method, then I can’t use TableView, and have to create TextFields my self. Which I feel is a step backwards.

Comment: @kleopatra yes, I have tables below that calculate total, and other columns that are not editable that need to match what the user entered (calculated from a rate table). If you don’t see the values change until you focus out, then you don’t know if your total matches your expected value.

Comment: @kleopatra also yes, it will only work for String, I tried to make it work with BigDecimal but it didn’t work, so what I do is I have a static method that tries to convert the user entered String to a BigDecimal, if it fails then it is null and all the sub totals, and calculations show up red/“- -“

Comment: @kleopatra `TableView` is supposed to support "always editing" cells, according to its documentation: "_It is your choice whether the cell is permanently in an editing state [...], or to switch to a different UI when editing begins [...]_". Unfortunately, this doesn't seem possible using the normal editing API—at least not simply. If you take a look at the implementation of `CheckBoxTableCell`, you'll see it does something similar to what the OP's doing.

Comment: @Slaw good point :) And interesting (read: never really seen it <g>), though not fully specified (or somewhat contradictory) in doc of tableView and checkBoxTableCell _permanently in an editing state_ vs. _not necessary to enter editing state_ ...

Comment: unrelated: you are not following fx naming conventions in LineItem - property accessors should be <name>Property (vs. get<Name>Property)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Row Selection Mode

Despite [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330430/how-to-use-arrow-buttons-to-traverse-cells-in-edit-mode-in-tableview?noredirect=1#comment97386683_55330430), it doesn't look like you need to enable [cell selection](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableSelectionModel.html#cellSelectionEnabledProperty) for this. Taking inspiration from the implementation of [`CheckBoxTableCell`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/CheckBoxTableCell.html), your custom `TableCell` should take some form of callback to get the model property; it can also require a [`StringConverter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/util/StringConverter.html), allowing you to use the `TableCell` with more than just `String`s. Here's an example:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView.TableViewFocusModel;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class CustomTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S, String>, TableCell<S, String>> forTableColumn(
            IntFunction<Property<String>> extractor) {
        return forTableColumn(extractor, new DefaultStringConverter());
    }

    public static <S, T> Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> forTableColumn(
            IntFunction<Property<T>> extractor, StringConverter<T> converter) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(extractor);
        Objects.requireNonNull(converter);
        return column -> new CustomTableCell<>(extractor, converter);
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<IntFunction<Property<T>>> extractor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "extractor");
    public final void setExtractor(IntFunction<Property<T>> callback) { extractor.set(callback); }
    public final IntFunction<Property<T>> getExtractor() { return extractor.get(); }
    public final ObjectProperty<IntFunction<Property<T>>> extractorProperty() { return extractor; }

    private final ObjectProperty<StringConverter<T>> converter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "converter");
    public final void setConverter(StringConverter<T> converter) { this.converter.set(converter); }
    public final StringConverter<T> getConverter() { return converter.get(); }
    public final ObjectProperty<StringConverter<T>> converterProperty() { return converter; }

    private Property<T> property;
    private TextField textField;

    public CustomTableCell(IntFunction<Property<T>> extractor, StringConverter<T> converter) {
        setExtractor(extractor);
        setConverter(converter);

        // Assumes this TableCell will never become part of a different TableView
        // after the first one. Also assumes the focus model of the TableView will
        // never change. These are not great assumptions (especially the latter),
        // but this is only an example.
        tableViewProperty().addListener((obs, oldTable, newTable) ->
                newTable.getFocusModel().focusedCellProperty().addListener((obs2, oldPos, newPos) -> {
                    if (getIndex() == newPos.getRow() && getTableColumn() == newPos.getTableColumn()) {
                        textField.requestFocus();
                    }
                })
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
            cleanUpProperty();
        } else {
            initializeTextField();
            cleanUpProperty();

            property = getExtractor().apply(getIndex());
            Bindings.bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), property, getConverter());

            setGraphic(textField);
            if (getTableView().getFocusModel().isFocused(getIndex(), getTableColumn())) {
                textField.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }

    private void cleanUpProperty() {
        if (property != null) {
            Bindings.unbindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), property);
            property = null;
        }
    }

    private void initializeTextField() {
        if (textField == null) {
            textField = new TextField();
            textField.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, this::processArrowKeys);
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
                if (isFocused) {
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focus(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void processArrowKeys(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getCode().isArrowKey()) {
            event.consume();

            TableViewFocusModel<S> model = getTableView().getFocusModel();
            switch (event.getCode()) {
                case UP:
                    model.focusAboveCell();
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    model.focusRightCell();
                    break;
                case DOWN:
                    model.focusBelowCell();
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    model.focusLeftCell();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new AssertionError(event.getCode().name());
            }
            getTableView().scrollTo(model.getFocusedCell().getRow());
            getTableView().scrollToColumnIndex(model.getFocusedCell().getColumn());
        }
    }

}
```

The example is not exhaustive and makes assumptions that are not guaranteed, but it's only an example and so I leave any tweaks up to you. One such improvement might be to include a [`TextFormatter`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TextFormatter.html) somehow. That said, I believe it provides the basic functionality you're looking for.

To use this cell, you would only set the `cellFactory` of each `TableColumn`. It is not necessary to set the `cellValueFactory` and doing so might actually be detrimental, depending on how `updateItem` gets called. Basically, it'd look something like:

```
TableView<YourModel> table = ...;

TableColumn<YourModel, String> column = new TableColumn<>("Column");
column.setCellFactory(CustomTableCell.forTableColumn(i -> table.getItems().get(i).someProperty()));
table.getColumns().add(column);
```

---

### Cell Selection Mode

This behavior you're attempting to implement seems inherently cell based, however, and as such it's probably better to enable cell selection. This allows the custom `TableCell` to base it's behavior on selection, rather than focus, and leaves the arrow key handling to the `TableView`. Here's a slightly modified version of the above example:

```
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.event.EventDispatcher;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class CustomTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T> {

    /* 
     * -- CODE OMITTED --
     *
     * The factory methods (forTableColumn) and properties (extractor
     * and converter) have been omitted for brevity. They are defined
     * and used exactly the same way as in the previous example.
     */

    private Property<T> property;
    private TextField textField;

    public CustomTableCell(IntFunction<Property<T>> extractor, StringConverter<T> converter) {
        setExtractor(extractor);
        setConverter(converter);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateSelected(boolean selected) {
        super.updateSelected(selected);
        if (selected && !isEmpty()) {
            textField.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
            clearProperty();
        } else {
            initializeTextField();
            clearProperty();

            property = getExtractor().apply(getIndex());
            Bindings.bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), property, getConverter());

            setGraphic(textField);
            if (isSelected()) {
                textField.requestFocus();
            }
        }
    }

    private void clearProperty() {
        if (property != null) {
            Bindings.unbindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), property);
            textField.setText(null);
            property = null;
        }
    }

    private void initializeTextField() {
        if (textField == null) {
            textField = new TextField();
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, wasFocused, isFocused) -> {
                if (isFocused && !isSelected()) {
                    getTableView().getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                }
            });

            /*
             * TableView has key handlers that will select cells based on arrow keys being
             * pressed, scrolling to them if necessary. I find this mechanism looks cleaner
             * because, unlike TableView#scrollTo, it doesn't cause the cell to jump to the
             * top of the TableView.
             *
             * The way this works is by bypassing the TextField if, and only if, the event
             * is a KEY_PRESSED event and the pressed key is an arrow key. This lets the
             * event bubble up back to the TableView and let it do what it needs to. All
             * other key events are given to the TextField for normal processing.
             *
             * NOTE: The behavior being relied upon here is added by the default TableViewSkin
             *       and its corresponding TableViewBehavior. This may not work if a custom
             *       TableViewSkin skin is used.
             */
            EventDispatcher oldDispatcher = textField.getEventDispatcher();
            textField.setEventDispatcher((event, tail) -> {
                if (event.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED
                        && ((KeyEvent) event).getCode().isArrowKey()) {
                    return event;
                } else {
                    return oldDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

---

### Notes

1. Neither approach works well when using `SelectionMode.MULTIPLE` (and actually selecting multiple rows/cells).
2. The `ObservableList` set on the `TableView` cannot have an [extractor](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.base/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList(javafx.util.Callback)) defined. For some reason this causes the table to select the next right cell when you type into the `TextField`.
3. *Only tested both approaches with JavaFX 12.*

Comment: Are you sure you can disable cell selection? It didn't work with it being turned off.

Comment: It works for me using JavaFX 12. To make sure I even explicitly set `cellSelectionEnabled` to false. Note that my example doesn't update the selection model to be in sync with the focus model, but it's still in "row selection" mode. There are some problems still; for instance, I sometimes get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if I've typed in the `TextField` before pressing an arrow key—not sure why yet.

Comment: afair, the focusedCell is null (or not fully configured) initially which might (or not didn't try) explain the IOOB

Comment: @kleopatra Yes, that's why in my answer I also had to add this : `textField.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> o, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) ->
        {
            if (newValue)
            {
                getTableView().getFocusModel().focus(getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableColumn());
            }
        }`

Comment: @kleopatra The problem seems to be from `scrollToColumnIndex`. For whatever reason, typing into the text field causes the focused cell property to update to a `TablePosition` whose column index is `-1`. It keeps the correct row focused, however.

Comment: the focusedProperty of the cell is always false in rowSelectionMode - which might lead to the -1 (== no column selected)

Comment: @trilogy Are you dead set on not using cell selection? There might be a cleaner feeling, less bug-prone way to do this by relying on selection rather than focus. But it really only works when in cell selection mode.

Comment: I'm ok with using CellSelection now, I realized it is probably better since users are able to go into cells that are not TextFields and start edit-mode in them.

Comment: @trilogy Updated answer with another option.

Comment: hmm ...can't reproduce the IOOBE (in fx11) - can you add an example of when it happens (at the best, I'm doing something wrong and at the worst, there might be a bug introduced in fx12 ;) Also, the UX when typing in the textField is somewhat broken: the caret remains at pos 0, thus pre-pending the typed char and the left/right arrow keys don't move the caret (no wonder, as they move the focusedcell ;)

Comment: a step further: happens if a row is selected and the extractor (of the list) acts on the column value - still not entirely certain why the extractor makes a difference: the cell is notified with/out any, always. Could be the selectionModel that reacts to the update and resets the column of the focusedCell to null ..

Comment: it's indeed the selectionModel's reaction to a list change of type update (which isn't really handled but falls-through in its itemsContentListener) - it re-selects the row via `select(row)` which calls `select(row, tableColumn)` with tableColumn==null for !cellSelectionEnabled -ultimately a bug, it shouldn't touch selection state at all on update events ...

Comment: and a hot fix seems to be to force the model's focusedCell in the keyHandler before doing any navigation ... and now 'nough fun, back to real work ;)

Comment: @kleopatra were you able to re-produce the IOOBE? I also was not able to.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out thanks to Slaw.

First to enable cell selection, `table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);`

then in the EditableTextCell.java class:

```
        this.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> o, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) ->
        {
            if (newValue)
            {
                textField.requestFocus();
            }

        });

        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> o, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) ->
        {
            if (newValue)
            {
                getTableView().getFocusModel().focus(getTableRow().getIndex(), getTableColumn());
            }
        }


        textField.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent ke) ->
        {
            switch (ke.getCode())
            {
                case DOWN:
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focusBelowCell();
                    ke.consume();
                    break;
                case ENTER:
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focusBelowCell();
                    ke.consume();
                    break;
                case UP:
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focusAboveCell();
                    ke.consume();
                    break;
                case RIGHT:
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focusRightCell();
                    ke.consume();
                    break;
                case LEFT:
                    getTableView().getFocusModel().focusLeftCell();
                    ke.consume();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
```