# TableView goes haywire when keeping arrow key pressed

Tags: java, javafx

By using this example to traverse an editable `TableView` using the arrow keys:

[How to use arrow buttons to traverse cells in edit mode in TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330430/how-to-use-arrow-buttons-to-traverse-cells-in-edit-mode-in-tableview)

A weird problem occurs when you keep the down arrow pressed. It seems to work fine for a bit, but if you press the down arrow key and the up arrow key, the table starts to get stuck in a loop of moving up and down really fast and you can't get out of it. It only happens if a scrollbar exists on the table, so that is why you have to add a few items to the table.

[image]

Here is my code:

**Test.java**

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        TableView<Model> table = new TableView();
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());
        table.getItems().add(new Model());

        table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
        TableColumn<Model, String> column = new TableColumn<>("Column");
        column.setCellFactory(CustomTableCell.forTableColumn(i -> table.getItems().get(i).getNameProperty()));
        table.getColumns().add(column);

        final Scene scene = new Scene(table);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public class Model
    {

        private SimpleStringProperty name;

        public Model()
        {
            name = new SimpleStringProperty();
        }

        /**
         * @return the string
         */
        public SimpleStringProperty getNameProperty()
        {
            return name;
        }

    }
}
```

**CustomTableCell.java**

```
package test;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.function.IntFunction;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.event.EventDispatcher;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.util.Callback;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;
import javafx.util.converter.DefaultStringConverter;

public class CustomTableCell<S, T> extends TableCell<S, T>
{

    public static <S> Callback<TableColumn<S, String>, TableCell<S, String>> forTableColumn(
            IntFunction<Property<String>> extractor)
    {
        return forTableColumn(extractor, new DefaultStringConverter());
    }

    public static <S, T> Callback<TableColumn<S, T>, TableCell<S, T>> forTableColumn(
            IntFunction<Property<T>> extractor, StringConverter<T> converter)
    {
        Objects.requireNonNull(extractor);
        Objects.requireNonNull(converter);
        return column -> new CustomTableCell<>(extractor, converter);
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<IntFunction<Property<T>>> extractor = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "extractor");

    public final void setExtractor(IntFunction<Property<T>> callback)
    {
        extractor.set(callback);
    }

    public final IntFunction<Property<T>> getExtractor()
    {
        return extractor.get();
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<IntFunction<Property<T>>> extractorProperty()
    {
        return extractor;
    }

    private final ObjectProperty<StringConverter<T>> converter = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(this, "converter");

    public final void setConverter(StringConverter<T> converter)
    {
        this.converter.set(converter);
    }

    public final StringConverter<T> getConverter()
    {
        return converter.get();
    }

    public final ObjectProperty<StringConverter<T>> converterProperty()
    {
        return converter;
    }

    private Property<T> property;
    private TextField textField;

    public CustomTableCell(IntFunction<Property<T>> extractor, StringConverter<T> converter)
    {
        setExtractor(extractor);
        setConverter(converter);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateSelected(boolean selected)
    {
        super.updateSelected(selected);
        if (selected && !isEmpty())
        {
                Platform.runLater(() -> textField.requestFocus());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty)
        {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
            clearProperty();
        } else
        {
            initializeTextField();
            clearProperty();

            property = getExtractor().apply(getIndex());
            Bindings.bindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), property, getConverter());

            setGraphic(textField);
            if (isSelected())
            {
                Platform.runLater(() -> textField.requestFocus());

            }
        }
    }

    private void clearProperty()
    {
        if (property != null)
        {
            Bindings.unbindBidirectional(textField.textProperty(), property);
            textField.setText(null);
            property = null;
        }
    }

    private void initializeTextField()
    {
        if (textField == null)
        {
            textField = new TextField();
            textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, wasFocused, isFocused) ->
            {
                if (isFocused && !isSelected())
                {
                    getTableView().getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
                }
            });

            /*
             * TableView has key handlers that will select cells based on arrow keys being
             * pressed, scrolling to them if necessary. I find this mechanism looks cleaner
             * because, unlike TableView#scrollTo, it doesn't cause the cell to jump to the
             * top of the TableView.
             *
             * The way this works is by bypassing the TextField if, and only if, the event
             * is a KEY_PRESSED event and the pressed key is an arrow key. This lets the
             * event bubble up back to the TableView and let it do what it needs to. All
             * other key events are given to the TextField for normal processing.
             *
             * NOTE: The behavior being relied upon here is added by the default TableViewSkin
             *       and its corresponding TableViewBehavior. This may not work if a custom
             *       TableViewSkin skin is used.
             */
            EventDispatcher oldDispatcher = textField.getEventDispatcher();
            textField.setEventDispatcher((event, tail) ->
            {
                if (event.getEventType() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED
                        && ((KeyEvent) event).getCode().isArrowKey())
                {
                    return event;
                } else
                {
                    return oldDispatcher.dispatchEvent(event, tail);
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce the problem. What version of JavaFX are you using? I tested using 12.0.2.

Comment: I was using JavaFX8

Comment: Hmm. Just downloaded and tried a Zulu distribution for Java 8u222 that included JavaFX—still can't reproduce. If you're using an older version then maybe a bug has been fixed. The problem should occur when pressing-and-holding the down arrow key and then simultaneously pressing-and-holding the up arrow key, correct? Because maybe I'm just doing it wrong.

Comment: I tested it and it occurred on 221  --- Are you able to hold down the "down" key and go right to the bottom of the table, and then hold the up key and go all the way up to the top? That's how I got it to do it.  I did figure it out though, that the "clear and select" had to be wrapped in a Platform.runlater...

Comment: Managed to reproduce the problem on 8u222. It seems to get stuck selecting over a range of items. For example, it'd select item 54, then 55, then 56, all the way to 63 and then go back to 54—over and over; this happened even after releasing the keys. I don't know why this problem occurs, but the `Platform.runLater` solution does appear to work.

Comment: Yep,  one thing though, I like the way it uses the natural TableView scroll using the arrow keys, but how can you do the same thing with the Enter key? As in Enter acts like a down arrow.

Comment: In a case like this I recommend using a loop for filling the `items` list. It results in much shorter code with less repetitions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, I had to wrap the "clearAndSelect" line in a `Platform.runLater()`

```
getTableView().getSelectionModel().clearAndSelect(getIndex(), getTableColumn());
```