# Can't seem to programmatically select TextField from TableCell (TextFieldTableCell-like) when adding a row to TableView (JavaFX 8)

Tags: javafx, tableview, textfield, tablecell

In JavaFX 8, I have created a custom TableCell with a TextField to get more control than with a "regular" TextFieldTableCell. What I want to achieve is to have that TextField automatically selected when an Add button is clicked (so the user doesn't have to click on that TextField or Tab to it after the Add-Record button is fired. Unfortunately, I only manage to select the row/cell but not the underlying TextField (and the startEdit() method doesn't seem to be reached).

Here is my code (Main FX Application code, POJO, FXML code created in Scene Builder, Controller code, and CustomTextFieldTableCell class):

**Main.java**

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

**POJO**

```
package test;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

class TestObject {

    private final SimpleStringProperty field1 = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private final SimpleStringProperty field2 = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public SimpleStringProperty field1Property() {
        return field1;
    }

    public void setField1(String string) {
        field1.set(string);
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty field2Property() {
        return field2;
    }

    public void setField2(String string) {
        field2.set(string);
    }



}
```

**FXMLDocument.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TableView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="425.0" prefWidth="517.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" fx:controller="test.FXMLDocumentController">
    <children>
        <Label fx:id="label" layoutX="126" layoutY="120" minHeight="16" minWidth="69" />
      <TableView fx:id="tableView" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="52.0" prefHeight="359.0" prefWidth="489.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="52.0">
        <columns>
          <TableColumn fx:id="col1" prefWidth="150.0" text="C1" />
          <TableColumn fx:id="col2" minWidth="0.0" prefWidth="141.0" text="C2" />
        </columns>
      </TableView>
      <Button fx:id="btnAdd" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="14.0" onAction="#handleAdd" text="_Add" />
    </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**FXMLDocumentController.java**

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private Button btnAdd;
    @FXML
    private TableView<TestObject> tableView;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TestObject, String> col1;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<TestObject, String> col2;

    @FXML
    private void handleAdd(ActionEvent event) {
        TestObject testObject = new TestObject();
        tableView.getItems().add(testObject);
        tableView.edit(tableView.getItems().indexOf(testObject), col1);
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        col1.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().field1Property());
        col1.setCellFactory((final TableColumn<TestObject, String> column) -> new CustomTextFieldTableCell());
        col1.setOnEditStart((TableColumn.CellEditEvent<TestObject, String> event) -> {
            //Inside code doesn't seem to ever get reached
            System.out.println("Edit started");
        });
        col2.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().field2Property());
        col2.setCellFactory((final TableColumn<TestObject, String> column) -> new TableCell<>());
    }    

}
```

**CustomTextFieldTableCell.java**

```
package test;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class CustomTextFieldTableCell extends TableCell<TestObject, String> {

    private final TextField textField;

    public CustomTextFieldTableCell() {
        textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            commitEdit(textField.getText());
            event.consume();
        });
        textField.prefWidthProperty().bind(prefWidthProperty().subtract(3));
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if (!isEditable()
                || getTableView() == null
                || getTableColumn() == null
                || getTableView() != null && !getTableView().isEditable()
                || getTableColumn() != null && !getTableColumn().isEditable()) {
            return;
        }
        super.startEdit();

        if (isEditing()) {
            /*
            textField.setText(getItem().trim());
            this.setText(textField.getText());
            */
            //Platform.runLater(() -> textField.requestFocus());
            textField.requestFocus();
        }
    }

    /** {@inheritDoc} */
    @Override
    public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setText(null);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            textField.setText(item == null ? "" : item.trim());
            setGraphic(textField);
        }
    }

}
```

What visually occurs:

[image]

What I need my code to do is to have caret placed inside the TextField or TextField focused, but this doesn't occur with my code right now.

[image]

Any idea what I am missing out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use arrow buttons to traverse cells in edit mode in TableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330430/how-to-use-arrow-buttons-to-traverse-cells-in-edit-mode-in-tableview)

Comment: I moved on to some other projects but will give it a try and post my findings here. Thank you very much for this investigation tip, @trilogy!